# Не работает стандартная тригонометрия

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задаю двумя точками направление. От первой точки влево и вправо на 90 градусов от направления нужно прорисовать ещё по одной точке (на заданном ранее расстоянии от первой).

Наткнулся на то, что стандартная тригонометрия тут не особо работает.

```
float dX = point2.x - point1.x;
float dY = point2.y - point1.y;
A = Mathf.Atan2(dY, dX);
var point_R_1 = new Vector2 (0.3925f * Mathf.Cos (A + 90.0f * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0.3925f * Mathf.Sin (A + 90.0f * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) + point1;
```

Так пробую добавить точку справа от первой.

Comment: Угол в `sin` передавали в градусах или радианах?

Comment: По-всякому пробовал...

Comment: Или тут дело ТОЛЬКО в синусе??

Comment: Тригонометрия работает, дело в коде, который пока мы не видели

Comment: Что значит по-всякому? Дело вообще в тригонометрических функциях, в Unity они принимают радианы и только радианы. Приведите свой код и, если есть возможность, визуализацию проблемы.

Comment: Для всего мира - работает, а для Вас - не работает?

Comment: Ну как-то так...

Comment: Выглядит правильно. Что не так получается? На тесте (0,0)-(1,1), расстояние 1.4142 какой результат?

Comment: @IncDD Я Вам еще раз говорю: "как-то так" - недостаточно. Добавьте в вопрос данные: ввод, получаемый и ожидаемый вывод. Или Вы ждете, что кто-то сделает это за Вас?

Comment: Согласен, действительно, не совсем точно задал. Эти точки рисуются в противоположную сторону, если вторую, задающую исходное направление ставить правее первой (То есть направление задавать слева направо). Не делаю вывод данных, так как между ними рисуются линии и видно так всё это безобразие)

Comment: Блин. Мне скоро неудобно тут вопросы задавать будет. Это всё дело было в линиях. При задавании параметра SetPosition LineRenderer'у был нарушен порядок одной точки. И она давала мне все эти кувыркания. На Unity недавно, так что не ругайте сильно ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @IncDD В таких случаях стоит сначала самому отдебажить результат через Debug.Log или Gizmos.

Comment: Gizmos’ом ещё толком не научился пользоваться. Вот дурные вопросы и вылазят.

Comment: А зря, очень полезная штука